# iOS Simulator launched by Appium, elements no longer inspectable by iOS Accessibility Inspector

Tags: java, iphone, appium, simulator

My iOS app has a collectionView that contains a headerView with another collectionView inside of it.

When the app is built and launched via xCode, the collectionView is inspectable using the iOS Accessibility Inspector.  When the app is launched via Appium for the Appium inspector, these same elements are no longer inspectable using the iOS Accessibility Inspector.

Killing the Appium server and re-launching the app on the sim shows the elements to be inspectable again.

Why/how is Appium changing the accessibility within my app?

Comment: what error do you get while trying to inspect the element using Appium Inspector?

Comment: No error, Appium inspector is unable to select the elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its the unique session id that it generates and communicates with a closed port number with the app and appium. So it holds the accessibility control of the app untill the session persists

Comment: Except that I am still able to inspect all of the other elements with both Appium inspector and iOS Accessibility Inspector. Just not these elements.